# Sass, same properties on diffrent class

Tags: css, sass

I have some code, which looks sth like this:

```
.elephant
    background: yellow

    .young-eph
         color: white

.tiger
    background: yellow

    .young-tgr
         color: white
```

How can I improve this code?

In css you can write same properties for multiple classes with comma

```
.elephant, .tiger {
     background: yellow
}
```

but how to do that with sass?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the same. Sass is transpiled to css, which means you can write good ole css in your .scss-files as well as sass.

**This is valid sass**:

```
.elephant, .tiger {
  background: yellow;
}

.elephant {
  border: dotted blue 1px;

  .young-eph {
    color: cyan;
  }
}

.tiger {
  border: dotted red 1px;

  .young-tgr {
    color: magenta;
  }
}
```

Here's a link to a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yXBxXJrPltN5E0TnyHfb).

**EDIT:** To your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481410/sass-same-properties-on-diffrent-class#answer-45481683):

```
.elephant
   background: yellow
   .young-eph
       color: white
       .very-young-eph
            padding-left: 30px
```

Maybe You can make a class `.animal` and inside `[class*="young-"]` and `[class*="very-young-"]` which you can then use to extend.

```
.animal
    background: yellow

    [class*="young-"] {
        color: white

        [class*="very-young-"] {
            padding-left: 30px
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much do the same thin as in normal css. Just put a comma in-between.

```
.elephant, .tiger {
  background: yellow

  .young-eph, .young-tgr {
    color: white
  }
}
```

In this case I'd replace .young-eph and .young-tgr by .young tho. having 2 different classes in this case looks redundant.

```
.elephant, .tiger {
  background: yellow

  .young {
    color: white
  }
}
```

EDIT after new info

If you have deep inheritance like that I'd just change the classes a bit. I generally avoid using extend.

if you use the classes .eph, .tgr, .adult, .young and .very
you can pretty much just do this:

```
.adult {
  background: yellow

  .young {
    color: white
    &.very { 
      padding-left: 30px;
    }
  }
}
```

& means the object has both .young and .very, so depending on needs you might not need it
you also most likely don't have to nest all of them, more code (including some html) might be nice.